# What permissions or role is required to install packages in a sandbox?

Tags: permissions, sandbox, package, roles

I am working with a client to install our package in their sandbox for testing. Can any user install a package or is there a "package installation permission" the user needs? Want to provide clear instructions to our client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

From the Help and training here:  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=distribution_installing_packages.htm